# convert python iterative method to parallel

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy, python-itertools

I am using python itertools and I have method that creates a product of the elements in an array. It looks like this:

```
import itertools as it
c=it.product('AB', repeat=10)
for elem in c:
     print (''.join(elem))
```

The result is:

```
AAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAB
AAAAAAAABA
AAAAAAAABB
AAAAAAABAA
AAAAAAABAB
.
.
.
BBBBBBBBBB
```

I am looking for a way to convert this iterative process to a matrix calculation. Would NumPy, or TensorFlow, or some other such method be of use in converting it? If so, how? Is this something better or more quickly done with a GPU?

Comment: Just generating the different product combinations using `product` is already as fast as it is, using another library won't make it faster. - You're not calculating anything

Comment: Did you calculate how many results this will give? What do you intend to do with the result?

Comment: The intent is to generate the different possibilities as quickly as possible. So speed is the deciding factor.

Comment: When you have the product, what are you then intending to do with it? Is it always just two elements, or is the amount variable?

Answer (score 1):

Generators and functions will work a little faster.

Generator:

```
import itertools as it
c=it.product('AB', repeat=10)
a = [''.join(elem) for elem in c]
```

Function:

```
import itertools as it
c=it.product('AB', repeat=10)
a = map(lambda x: ''.join(x),c)
```